# gitignore for App-engine connected android project

Tags: android, eclipse, git, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

I need to collaborate on an App-engine Connected Android Project (AECAP). I am using GitHub as the repo. Eclipse has no option for creating AECAP from existing source (as does android and other java projects -- so google needs to fix this). Anyway, in order to have collaborators work smoothly with the AECAP, how should I setup git? I am guessing the answer has to do with the `gitignore` file. I am hoping the google experts or someone with experience out there can help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the `.gitignore` file is involved, you can use the [GitHub gitignore project](https://github.com/github/gitignore) to get one.

See for instance [**Android.gitignore**](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore).

But you also can consider adding a [**`.gitattributes`** file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html), in order to manage and control the end-of-line normalization.

See for instance [this `.gitattributes` file](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/source/browse/.gitattributes).

Comment: these links are quite generic. There is nothing particular to App-engine Connected Android Project

Comment: @learner that would be because there isn't much to ignore. When you look at an actual App-engine connected android project like https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android, its `.gitignore` is even shorter than the ones I propose: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android/blob/master/.gitignore